# Connecting jumpercable to gpio pins

Tags: gpio, led, cable

My teacher gave me a large group of jumper cables attached to one another.

[image]

[image]

this might be a stupid question but if it's attached like on the on the bottom picture what is the order of the cables? (grey, top left pin, red top right?)

Thank you Kindly!

Comment: Have you asked your teacher this question?

Comment: I won't be able to speak to him for a few weeks, so I thought I'd ask it here

Comment: It's still a reasonable question, @Seamus. After all, the OP could have found the cable in a box on the attic with no teacher to ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a [Ribbon Cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_cable) here. Which according to Wikipedia could be color-coded to reduce the risk of reversed connections:

> To make it easier to identify individual conductors in a cable; ribbon-cable manufacturers introduced rainbow ribbon cable, which uses a repeating pattern of colors borrowed from the standard resistor color code (Brown is pin 1 or pin 11 or pin 21, etc. Red is pin 2 or pin 12 or pin 22, etc.). It is sometimes known affectionately to its users as "hippie cable" due to its distinct appearance.

Your cable seems to feature just that color scheme (Brown, Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Violet, Grey, White, Black). Unfortunately and this is the big caveat here is pin 1 of the Pi's GPIO header at the opposite corner - where it reads "Made in the UK" on the PCB not near the USB receptacles. So you need to flip the connector around by 180°, i.e. with the cables towards the Pi not outwards. Or using your picture - with the brown cable being at the bottom, not the top. In which case brown would be Pin 1, i.e. bottom right, and red would be Pin 2, i.e. bottom left.

If in doubt use a voltmeter to check!

Comment: thanks, do you know where I can find the gpio pins I need to use to connect a Neopixel lightstrip? I have this link here: https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/using-neopixels-with-the-raspberry-pi. But connecting it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Juriaan Assuming you have connected GND and +5V you need to pick a data pin from  GPIO10, 12, 18 or 21 - and likely configure it in the code. Note that GPIO pin numbering (as used in software) is NOT the same as pin numbers of the header itself (the physical pin). To make it even more complicated are there two different numbering schemes (BCM and BOARD), though I would assume BCM unless it's indicated otherwise. At first glance I cannot tell from thepihut's description. See https://pinout.xyz/